# Exportar archivo con varias tablas

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hola Buenas tardes espero alguien me pueda dar una idea con este asunto

Tengo mi base de datos con varias tablas (usuarios, facturas, tipos, marcas, equipos, componentes ...). Uno de los requerimientos del sistema es que el usuario pueda generar un archvio .csv para poder mandar sus reportes a otra empresa, esta empresa pide que la información vaya en cierto orden y con ciertos datos , son practicamente 50 campos que debe contener este .csv por cada equipo, se reportara información de marca, modelo, serie , usuario, componentes internos del equipo, capacidades etc.

Le comentaré como lo intento resolver y solicito sugerencia por si existe otra alternativa más eficiente que me pudieran dar. Gracias

Tengo una consulta con 10 join a diferentes tablas , con la finalidad de obtener la información básica. 
Una de las tablas contiene los componentes de un equipo de computo (RAM, DD, SO,CPU etc) En dicha tabla se puede tener 2 o 3 registros de RAM para una PC y lo mismo para cada componente pues cada máquina puede tener varios.
En el archivo .csv me solicitan por cada fila:

- •    número de equipo,
  • responsable, 
  •    factura, 
  •    garantía
  • y lo que se me complica es ¿Cuantos discos tiene?, cuanta capacidad, cuanta RAM etc, esto debido a que esta información no la conseguiré con un solo query ya que tendría que hacer una para saber cuántos CPU's , otra para la capacidad total de almacenamiento dependiendo de cuantos Discos duros tenga la pc...

Luego la información la presento en una tabla con un query en ciclo que muestre cada fila, pero a la vez en los casos de ciertas columnas donde requiero otro query para presentar la información(numero de discos, capacidades...), hice una función donde mando 3 parámetros que me permiten definir que query se ejecutará para obtener la información para esta columna y esa función me sirve como para 30 de las 50 columnas.

Al final hago lo necesario para exportar esta consulta como un archivo .csv

El dilema en todo esto es ¿Existe otra forma? se que esto que hice funciona pero si analizará el hecho de que esta tabla crecerá y que con el tiempo por fila se estarán ejecutando cerca de 30 querys y si tuviera tan solo 10 filas ya serían 300 querys y esto carga a la BD; realmente se debe pensar en una solución que además de resolver el problema no genere exceso de carga en el sistema gestor de Base de Datos,  ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto gracias por la bienvenida